# Can I use random IP from ALL exit nodes?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Would it be possible to use random exit node (from 1 bar to 3 bar nodes in Tor network map from vidalia) instead of using the strongest exit node? Would it be possible to do this via torrc or telnet? I need a random IP instead of one of most common ones (best bandwidth).

Answer (score 1):

The Tor client completely controls the policy of which nodes to use and you're free to use a modified version of Tor if you like.

Therefore, yes, you can use a random exit node. However, if you use a different policy from the default:

- You will get a worse service, because you might be choosing slow or overloaded nodes
- You will be easier to identify, because the behavior of choosing random nodes may be distinctive to origin-servers.
- You will still need to respect the nodes exit-policy, or you'll get no service at all

I don't think there's an easy way of changing the whole exit-node policy without modifying the Tor source code. You can change some timings and forbid / force certain nodes to be used. You can choose a particular set of exit nodes if you like (but this is a labor-intensive and unreliable setup).

Answer (score 1):

In your `torrc` you can use the [`ExcludeExitNodes` directive](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExcludeExitNodes) to exclude the 'strongest' exit node(s) that you want to avoid.
Alternatively you can use the `ExitNodes` directive to specify a set that you want to use, but that is probably more work and not necessary.
Additionally you can set `StrictNodes 1`. This will force your Tor client to honor the `ExitNodes` and `ExcludeExitNodes` even if that means failure to create a circuit.

This is probably the closest you can get to what you want in an easy way.

If that is not good enough and you're willing to spend some time and effort and research and wizardry on it, you could look at using the `SETCONF` command to change the exit node restrictions over the [Control Protocol](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/control-spec.txt). Write a script that periodically parses the consensus, applies your personal logic to come up with a set of acceptable exit nodes, picks one (or better: a few), sets that (those) as your exit(s).